# Disable unity panel popping up on file drag

Tags: unity, mouse, panel, drag-and-drop

My problem is the unity panel popping up when I'm dragging a file with the mouse. I currently have the panel set to auto-hide with the lowest sensitivity value, so it normally only pops up when I press the super key.

If I open nautilus and drag a file even a little bit, then the unity panel will pop up to let you drag the file onto one of its programs.

I'm trying to use an application that has a menu bar on the left of the window where I can drag files onto the menu, but the unity panel keeps popping up and blocking me from dropping my files on the application window.

Is there a setting to disable the auto-popup on file drag?